# R - pivot data frame with dynamic column names and no aggregation

Tags: r

I need to pivot my data frame and create columns based on values in one of the columns. My data frame is as follows:

```
REPORT_ID   NBR CD  abc_val item_name
752918618   LN  AAA 5173    hours_start
752918618   LN  AAA PO      phase_start
752918618   LN  AAA 5175    hours_end
752918618   LN  AAA 1       ind_end
752918618   LN  AAA 151447  cooldown
752918618   LN  AAA TA      phase_end
752918618   LN  AAA 141151  start_time
752918618   LN  AAA 1       ind_star
```

and I need the below result. As you can see, eight columns were added with text "abc_val" and the value from column "item_name". Also, after they were created they got value from abc_val.

```
    REPORT_ID   NBR CD  abc_valhours_start  abc_valphase_start  abc_valhours_end    abc_valind_end  abc_valcooldown abc_valphase_end    abc_valstart_time   abc_valstart_time   abc_valind_star
    752918618   LN  AAA 5173                PO                  5175                1                151447         TA                  TA                  141151              1
```

The code for df creation is here as well:

```
REPORT_ID <- c(752918618,752918618,752918618,752918618,752918618,752918618,752918618,752918618)
NBR <- c("LN","LN","LN","LN","LN","LN","LN", "LN")
CD <- c("AAA","AAA","AAA","AAA","AAA","AAA","AAA", "AAA")
abc_val <- c("5173","PO", "5175", "1", "151447", "TA", "141151", "1")
item_name <- c("hours_start", "phase_start", "hours_end", "ind_end", "cooldown", "phase_end", "start_time", "ind_star")


df <- data.frame(REPORT_ID, NBR, CD, abc_val, item_name)
```

I hope the snapshot of my data explain what I am after :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve it

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(item_name = item_name %>% str_c("abc_val",.)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = item_name,values_from = abc_val)
```

Comment: `library(tidyverse)` if you haven't loaded it.

Comment: @dyrland Well said

Comment: Brilliant. I tried so many different packages and had it already added. Your help is much appreciated. Any idea the easiest way to add prefix "abc_val" to all created columns?